# UIRefreshControl backward compatibility

Tags: objective-c, ios, uirefreshcontrol

I am writing an iOS app with XCode 4.5 and iOS SDK 6.0. I am using UIRefreshControl in my app and my device runs iOS 6.0.1. The UIRefeshControl works fine on this. What would happen if I were to run this app on a device with previous iOS version? Would the refreshcontrol still work or do I have to use some other tool to implement this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIRefreshControl` only supported by iOS 6 now. Try this: [ODRefreshControl](https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl)

Comment: Thanks. :) I'm new to iOS development, so please clear this doubt. I was under the impression that the usage of external libraries in an iOS app would lead to its rejection. Isn't this an external library? :)

Comment: I met this control in several apps in top of AppStore and used several controls like this in my apps. So,don't worry,if smth is bad or uses private api(that may cause rejection) it won't be so popular between developers=)